# Removed .* from regex broke regex

Tags: regex, vbscript, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code and it did contain .* but I removed them.
This is the line I changed:

```
>>%vbs% echo regex.pattern="\nName=%~1\n"
```

This used to be:

```
>>%vbs% echo regex.pattern="\nName=.*%~1.*\n"
```

but it was searching the line when words preceded or succeeded the variable too. I only want it to search for an exact match of Name=(variable). Variable is var6.

The reason for me wanting to fix this is because I am looking to remove the wildcards when it searches for var6 after "Name=". Because I want only "Name=var6" to be found and changed, not "Name=(sometext)var6(sometext)".

The first line above doesn't work and the second line above searches for the wildcards before and afert he variable, so that isn't what I want. What am I doing wrong in the first line above?

Here is the extended code (line in question is midway down):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
find "!var6!" < "Campaign_SCR2.mis.tmp" >nul && (
call :replace "!var6!"
call :stripdup "Campaign_SCR2.mis.tmp.tmp2" "Campaign_SCR2.mis.tmp" "(Class=.*\nType=.*\nOrigin=.*\nS    ide=.*)\nClass=.*\nType=.*\nOrigin=.*\nSide=.*" "$1"
del "Campaign_SCR2.mis.tmp.tmp2"
)
)
)
goto Loop
goto :EOF

:replace
set vbs="%temp%\%random%.vbs"
if exist %vbs% goto :replace

>%vbs% echo set regex=new regexp
>>%vbs% echo regex.global=true
>>%vbs% echo regEx.IgnoreCase=False
>>%vbs% echo regex.pattern="\nName=%~1\n"
>>%vbs% echo wscript.stdOut.write regex.replace    (wscript.stdin.readall,"Name=ShipDummy"+vbCRLF+"Class=ShipDummy"+vbCRLF+"Type=0"+vbCRLF+"Origin=Environmental"+vbCRLF+"Side=0"+vbCRLF)
cscript /nologo %vbs% <"Campaign_SCR2.mis.tmp" >"Campaign_SCR2.mis.tmp.tmp2"
del %vbs%
goto :EOF


:stripdup
set vbs="%temp%\%random%.vbs"
if exist %vbs% goto :stripdup


 >%vbs% echo set regex=new regexp
>>%vbs% echo regex.global=true
>>%vbs% echo regEx.IgnoreCase=False
>>%vbs% echo regex.pattern="%~3"
>>%vbs% echo wscript.stdOut.write regex.replace(wscript.stdin.readall,"%~4")
cscript /nologo %vbs% <"%~1" >"%~2"
del %vbs%
goto :EOF



:exitloop4
:Loop
```

I've tried different values for var6 (which would be %~1 in the regex). I've tried values with spaces and without spaces, and no luck.

Comment: You should be looking to remove the batch from your VBScript. Seriously, why are you doing this to yourself? Building a VBScript to do the actual work and making everything completely unreadable is practically all your batch code does, so you could just as well do this in plain VBScript.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's why I made it a comment, not an answer. Of course you're free to complicate your own life as much as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about (I am just guessing this is what you want)

```
>>%vbs% echo regex.pattern="[\w]*Name=[\w]*%~1[\w]*"
```

This will match on

```
(Any whitespace)Name=(Any Whitespace)var6(Any Whitespace)
```

Or

```
>>%vbs% echo regex.pattern=".*[\w]*Name=[\w]*%~1[\w]*.*"
```

This will match on

```
(Anything)(Any whitespace)Name=(Any Whitespace)var6(Any Whitespace)(Anything)
```

**Note:** By the way, I do not see anywhere in your script where `var6` is being set!  If it is never set then it will always be a blank string.

Comment: Hi, yes var6 is set above this script.